# How to download photos via URL from outlook365 to powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to use VBA Powerpoint to directly download a picture via URL and place it in the current powerpoint presentation. This is working for common and open URLs like 
 'http://finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=INTC&ty=c&ta=0&p=w&s=l'

Unfortunately the error message "Run-time error '70': Permission denied" is popping up while executing the line 'thePix.Fill.UserPicture imageURL' in case I am using the outlook.office365.com adress to download pictures from the company mail server?!.

What exactly is the problem there? Is there a need to somehow also transmit the login data for this specific server? How can this be archieved? Can someone please help me?

```
Sub AddImage()
Dim thePix As Shape
Dim imageURL As String

Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide

imageURL = "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=XXX@YY.com&UA=0&size=HR648x648"
'imageURL = "http://finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=INTC&ty=c&ta=0&p=w&s=l"

For Each thePix In sld.Shapes
    thePix.Fill.UserPicture imageURL
Next thePix

End Sub
```

Thank you very much and BR
Martin

Comment: Are you able to access the photos in a browser or something? If these photos are privileged/require logging in or authentication, check how the server/site authenticates your request (e.g. cookie in response to a successful log-in form submission?). You may need to emulate the authentication process by sending any necessary HTTP request(s). Also, might be worth trying to firstly save files to disk, then `fill` using the locally stored version of the image. With this approach, you can verify if the server's response contains any photo(s).

Comment: I can access the files via browser (e.g. Google Chrome). In icognito modus this is not possible. Therefore I believe that it requires some kind of authentification to the server, but the question is "how do I do that via VBA and download the pic via URL afterwards?" -  a temporary download to a local disk would also be very okay, filling it afterwards is not the problem.

Comment: Figure out which site/service you're logged in to (in the regular, non-incognito browser window), might just be Outlook. Then you need to mimic the log in process (on some sites this can be done by sending HTTP post request with a URL encoded form in the request's body, to which the server responds with a cookie. If you include that cookie in subsequent requests, you can access privileged resources). To know what exactly what needs to be POSTed to the server, you can log in a browser whilst monitoring the network tab in Developer Tools (F12 in Chrome).